# Antonyms mean the same thing in context

Tags: terminology

I'm aware of the existence of [auto-antonyms/contranyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym), but I'm looking for something that seems to be the opposite: a situation in which either word in a set of antonyms results in the same meaning. To be clear, a contranym requires antonymous homographs; I am searching for two *distinct* words that are antonyms but convey the same meaning in context. For example, the following sentences mean the same thing:

- How is your homework ***coming***?
- How is your homework ***going***?

The only other example I can think of at the moment is "slow ***up/down***", although there are probably others. (I keep telling myself to write them down as I come across them, but that's a separate issue.)

Additionally, I recognize that there may be a subtle difference in connotation that I'm missing. In the situations I've presented, do the two words mean *exactly* the same thing, or is it inappropriate to use on in certain cases? To me it has always just been the one that comes more naturally in speech, but I believe I use the coming/going example both ways equally as often.

**Edit:** I should state that I'm wondering if a term for such a situation exists; I am not searching for more examples, although those are welcome!

Comment: hot/cool as slang terms from something good?

Comment: You don't use "what's coming on here?" in place of "what's going on here?". I don't think coming and going are interchangeable except your example. That's why you cannot find so many examples.

Comment: How is your homework coming sounds rather odd to me; I think 'How is your homework coming along.' sounds a lot better.

Comment: @Rathony: I never suggested "coming" and "going" always mean the same thing. If that were the case, they would cease being antonyms. My question pertains to situations in which the context allows this.

Comment: @dpwilson What I wanted to mean was "How is your homework coming" doesn't sound the same with "going". Ronald already commented.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's a regional thing, because to me "How is your homework coming" comes more naturally to me than "going".

Comment: Does the  pair good/bad fits the bill ? "You're a good girl" can mean the same thing in the right context as "you're a bad girl"; "He gave him a very bad beating" equivalent to "he gave him a very good beating"

Comment: Fill in / fill out (a form)

Comment: Coming and Going is not a case of antonymy. Rather, it's a side effect of [Deixis](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html);  much more complicated than simple opposition.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what you're looking for, I've come across a slightly broader class, [hyponyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy). A hyponym-hypernym pair is an is-a relationship between two words. One of the examples in the link is that *blue* and *red* are co-hyponyms of *colour* (their hypernym).

In your example, *coming* and *going* are both hyponyms of *moving*; other movement-related words also fit your sentence template - e.g. "How is your homework travelling?" The hyponyms you selected happen to be antonyms, which is an interesting result of the conflict between their respective connotations of *movement* vs *direction*.

This also seems to hold true for the hot/cool and in/out examples others have provided in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

"Opposonym" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3A-onym#Opposonym.3F)).  That's all I was able to find.  There doesn't seem to be a formally defined term for it.